# How do you load a saved game in FFVI

Tags: emulation, final-fantasy-6

So, I finally started playing Final Fantasy 6 (well, Final Fantasy 3 technically) and I'm really enjoying it. Except, now I've saved my game after a few hours of play, but when I (yes, you guessed it) restart my emulator and start the game, I'm given no option to load my game.

This is sort of debugging stuff. I'm trying to figure out if my EMU (ZSnes for Windows) corrupted the save, or if I'm just missing how you load the game. When I start it, I get the FF3 splash screen, I hit A, and I immediately get a new game fired up. Not ideal

During my first session, when I'd reach save points, it would show my already-saved game. When I'd die (which happened a few times), it would load my game successfully.

So idk what went south. If you have any ideas on the grand issue, I'm happy to hear them. Otherwise, simply, how do you load a game on FFVI?

Comment: Sounds like you saved the game properly, and not just in save states.  Have you done any file maintenance perchance?  Where is the emulator located?

Comment: If you save a game in an emulator it saves in a file. So as fbueckert said, have you moved the emulator directory or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the answer to my question is:

Once the game loads the splash screen, and then starts an (apparently) unskippable video where Terra and the two soldier guys chat on the cliffside, and then walk while more credits roll, after that the game will show you the load screen.

Man that's a terrible place for a load screen. I guess my Emulator was working correctly all along; I just didn't realize that FF3 would put a load screen so freakin deep into the game (it would be like a 5 minute wait if it weren't for the fast-forward button on my Emulator).

**EDIT:**
Jeez. I must not have been thinking too hard yesterday. As the comments indicated, YES, you can skip that intro video (default: 'x' in ZSNES).

Anyway, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: ...Pretty sure that's skippable.

Comment: Ya know, I would have thought so too. The part where they're walking and the credits are rolling is, but it seems like the part leading up to that isn't...or maybe I'm not hitting the right button or something.

Comment: That should be skippable. As I recall you can hit anything and go right to the title screen.